# Deploying webapp and worker to Heroku from github

Tags: node.js, heroku, procfile

I have a web app which I setup the continuous deployment from github. However I'm planning to add some worker roles to this app and I'm wondering couple of things. I'm using Node.js.

In my mind, I had the design like:

- Procfile would have the # of web and worker dynos.
- Worker type can be a different deployment, but all I can see is it has a different start command. How does this work with the package management? What if the stuff that I require in the worker role is different than the stuff in the web app?

So my questions are?

- Any chance that I can use the same repository and structure it in a way that the worker and web code is maintained in the same location? Can I have `/web` and `/worker` folders in the root which have different `app.js` and `package.json` files so I have them in the same repo, but their dependencies are managed differently. How can I make this work when deploying to Heroku?
- I have some 3rd party libraries which I've installed to the web app via build packs, but I want them to be present in the worker roles. These are necessary for some of the computations that I want to do, so I'm planning to use the worker role for dequeue and process. Any way to install build packs on the worker role?
- What's the right way of managing this through the Procfile? Can I set the number of worker roles I want in the proc file or do I need to scale up / down using the command line and that's the only option that I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is entirely possible. All you need to do is have a global `package.json` file to manage your dependencies (you can't manage separate dependencies with worker and web role). If the `package.json` is not enough to make heroku detect that you're using `Node.Js` which was a problem I've faced; add the buildpack of `heroku/nodejs` and you should be ok. Whatever buildpack is installed, it will be available on the worker role.

Regarding the different directories, this is what I have now:

```
/web
/worker
/package.json
/Procfile
```

And my procfile is:

```
web: npm start --prefix /web
worker: npm start --prefix /worker
```

which seemed to fix the startup problem. There isn't any way of setting the #of dynos in the Procfile.